# dynamic_cast crashes my program

Tags: c++, crash, dynamic-cast

In my program I have a base class (`ship`) and four derived classes (`pirate`, `mercantile`, `repairing`, `exploring`) and in a member function of `repairing` I want to know if an object pointed by a `ship *` is of type `pirate` in order to be able to handle that case.

So in that member function I have the following `if`:

```
ship * shp;

shp = map[i][j]->getShip(); //random initialization of shp

if( (dynamic_cast<pirate *>(shp)) == NULL)  // <- program doesn't enter here  
{ . . . }                                   //      while it should
```

But during the runtime I noticed that sometimes the program didn't entered the `if` even when `shp` was pointing to a non-`pirate` object (e.g. `exploring`) .

So I tried to see the result of that `boolean` value inside the `if` by writing the following code:

```
pirate *prt;
bool test;
if(map[i][j]->getShip()!=0){
    prt = dynamic_cast<pirate *>(shp);  //  <- program crashes here
    test = ( prt == NULL );
    cout<<test<<endl;
}
```

But after compiling and trying to run this, the program crashes just at the time `dynamic_cast` is used.

So, probably `dynamic_cast` isn't working correctly and this is the reason it is not entering the `if` in the previous code.

Note that I have used the same method with `dynamic_cast` in the rest of my programm to find out the type of an object and it worked properly.

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278429/what-could-cause-a-dynamic-cast-to-crash

Comment: If you're inside the first if statement it implies the casting has failed and shp is probably looking some invalid value. Therefore, the second attempt to dynamic_cast shp (which is likely in an invalid state) will cause crash. You need to post more code for further clarification.

Comment: `map[i][j]->getShip()` Are you 100% sure that i and j are valid and you are not stepping out of bounds of map? I assume map is a 2d array.

Comment: I don't recommend naming your variables the same as standard classes (`map`).

Comment: `Note that I have used the same method with dynamic_cast in the rest of my programm to find out the type of an object and it worked properly`  We don't know what `map` is.  We don't know the values of `i` or `j`.  Wouldn't it be a little more helpful if you posted what `map` was, and exactly what are the values of `i` and `j` when your program crashes?

Comment: Problem solved!

`dynamic_cast` was crashing because of my mistake. 

`shp` was not initialized when trying to downcast it, so that's why `dynamic_cast` crashed.

@jazaman @PaulMcKenzie I should have posted more code as you said.
I suppose the reason it's not entering the first `if` is a mistake in the code that is missing.

I ll post the rest of the code if I don't manage to figure out that mistake.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: The precise reason we have namespaces is so that `map` is not colliding with `std::map`. This is intentionally OK.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, the cause was not initializing `ship`. More fundamentally, `dynamic_cast<Derived>(baseptr)` requires that `baseptr` must point to a live `Base` object or be `nullptr`. E.g. it won't work either if the pointer was initialized, but the object then deleted.